# Error message in if statement doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm building a horoscope generator and for some reason, all if/else statements to determine the astrological sign work but the last one which is the 'error' that should return invalid input, whenever the day is >= 32 || day === 0 doesn't show the message.

Here's the code: https://playcode.io/671371/

Comment: if (month === true && day === 0 || month === true && day >= 32); 
<-- you have a semiclolomn after the condition... just remove it

Comment: Please include your code in the body of your question. You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code. More formatting help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and condense your code down to a [mre]. We ask for a MRE because (a) it's not the most efficient use of time to  read lines after lines of irrelevant code looking for what's wrong, and 
(b) often, the exercise of creating a MRE helps you isolate and identify the problem and helps you fix the issue yourself.

Comment: [You can also include runnable snippets of HTML/CSS/JS directly into your question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Any reason this couldn't be simplified to `<input type="date">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud put this on top of your function, because after the first valid condition, your function will be left by `return`.

By the way: there are 5 months with less than 31 days. 4 have 30 days, 1 has 28 or 29 days.